# Payload for the Watch App Notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

When creating a new Apple Watch App in Xcode, the following APNS payload example is created:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "Test message",
            "title": "Optional title"
        },
        "category": "myCategory"
    },

    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
        {
            "title": "First Button",
            "identifier": "firstButtonAction"
        }
    ],

    "customKey": "Use this file to define a testing payload for your notifications. The aps dictionary specifies the category, alert text and title. The WatchKit Simulator Actions array can provide info for one or more action buttons in addition to the standard Dismiss button. Any other top level keys are custom payload. If you have multiple such JSON files in your project, you'll be able to select them when choosing to debug the notification interface of your Watch App." }
```

I am confused by the use of body and title within the alert dictionary. The following payload is ordinarily used in iOS apps:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Test message",
        "title": "Opt title",
        "category": "default"
    },
    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
        {
            "title": "First Button",
            "identifier": "firstButtonAction"
        }
    ],

    "customKey": "Use this file to define a testing payload for your notifications. The aps dictionary specifies the category, alert text and title. The WatchKit Simulator Actions array can provide info for one or more action buttons in addition to the standard Dismiss button. Any other top level keys are custom payload. If you have multiple such JSON files in your project, you'll be able to select them when choosing to debug the notification interface of your Watch App."
}
```

Which is the correct way? Although a default payload file is created in this way, the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW8) provides a screenshot using the latter variant.

Comment: I can confirm that the first variation does work. That is the form we use for our payloads. Our app is live in the store.

Comment: Yes but I can confirm the second one also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20160827193216/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)(Table 3-1), the value type of `alert` key can be **string or dictionary**, as Dhawal said, both formats are correct.

If `alert` is dictionary, it can contain `title`, `body`, `title-loc-key` etc(Table 3-2). What's the purpose of `title` key? This key was added in iOS 8.2 which contain WatchKit, and WatchKit has a Short-Look Notification interface, there is no enough space for full notification, so Apple Watch use `title` to describe the purpose of the notification and display in Short-Look Notification.

[image]
<sub>(source: [edgekey.net](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/watch/human-interface-guidelines/app-components/images/app-components-short-look_2x.png))</sub>

In this picture, "Gray's Birthday" is the `title` in `alert`. Because you can't see Short-Look Notification in simulator, you should test result of `title` key in REAL Apple Watch.

Comment: Great tip, I tested it using my real Apple Watch and the bottom variant does not work, only the upper variant using the alert dictionary and the title key. Screenshot in Apple docs appears faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the **Apple** documentation, here is the following keys that you can have in the `aps` dictionary: `alert`, `badge`, `sound` and `content-available`. And here is keys that you can have in the `alert` dictionary: title, body, title-loc-args etc. You can check it the Push Notification Programming Guide for more information here:
[Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

Check this as well for your **WatchKit Extension**, [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1)

Also, the second way you describe should be the correct way. I just create a **Watch App** and it includes the sample payload. And the `category` is put inside the `aps` outside the `alert` which should be incorrect in this case. Hope this helps. It means that `aps` can only contain those four default properties. So, `category` should be contained inside the `alert`.

Comment: That documents seems outdated because the category key is also not mentioned.

Comment: It's not actually. From the **Apple Watch Programming Guide**, it also suggests you to go to the **Push Notification Programming Guide** as a reference.

Comment: Yes but the second way should also be correct; look at the example screenshot in the documentation link I provided..

Comment: Based on your links, both using alert as a string and alert as a dictionary are correct. The question is where the new "title" key must be placed; within alert dictionary or at the same level?

Comment: I've now confirmed the second variant works as expected though, and it does not explain the other page of Apple docs mentioned in my opening post. Besides the document is not complete, it does not mention the category key.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading too fast and did not notice that. `aps` can only contain `alert`, `badge`, `sound` and `content-available`. So, `category` should be included in the `alert`. I will update the answer accordingly. So, yes. Second should be the correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Documentation for Push Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) has mentioned a Note,

> Note: If you want the device to display the message text as-is in an
>   alert that has both the Close and View buttons, then specify a string
>   as the direct value of alert. Don’t specify a dictionary as the value
>   of alert if the dictionary only has the body property.

So as per above note, both formats are correct but we should use second format (alert with directly text value instead of dictionary) when you only need body property in Alert. If you need to use other child properties of Alert like body, title,...then you should use first format (Alert with dictionary as value).